# Problemas con CORS nodejs y Angular

Tags: nodejs, angular, cors

Estoy realizando una webapp mediante el MEAN stack. El caso es que ahora he desarrollado un método para poder registrar objetos en la base de datos, pero cuando lo ejecuto, resulta un error:

> Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 404

He estado investigando un poco, y por lo visto está en el CORS. O sea, el problema está en mi servidor. Voy a app.js en la parte del api, realizada con NodeJS, y este el código realizado:

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-API-KEY, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Access-Control');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, PUT, POST, OPTIONS, DELETE');
  res.header('Allow', 'GET, PUT, POST, OPTIONS, DELETE');
  res.header('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8'); 
  return next();
});
```

¿Se puede saber donde existe el error? He mirado más formas, pero no doy con ello.

Comment: Estás consumiendo una API o algo parecido para atacar al servidor?. SI estás utilizando algún tipo de API lo más probable es que tengas el error en el back.

Comment: Solo con las tres primeras lineas de `res.header` ya te debería funcionar. Comprueba **el orden** para ese fragmento de código (debería estar ubicado antes de las rutas y del `listen`)
Puedes probar con **Postman**, a ver si así te va (Postman no tiene en cuenta CORS), y si no, postea aquí el mensaje de error que te muestre.
También sería interesante que nos postearas qué mensaje de error te aparece en el **navegador** (debería estar en la consola)

Comment: Ya conseguí encontrar el fallo. Resulta que era un problema en el modelo de Nodejs. Muchas gracias por la atención prestada. De todas formas, hay algo que no entiendo, porque me daba ese error cuando el fallo estaba en otro sitio, o sea, quiero decir, era de otro "tipo".

Comment: ¿Puedes poner la solución? Puede ayudar a otros con problemas similares...

Comment: De acuerdo, si puede ayudar al resto... aunque no es gran cosa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema estaba en que al ejecutar el método que había creado para la inserción de nuevos registros en la base de datos, me resultaba un error. Investigando, me acerqué a la solución al parecer. Por lo visto, era un problema relacionado con el CORS (Cross-Origin Resource-Sharing, en castellano: Intercambio de recursos de origen cruzado), resultando el error que especifiqué en la pregunta.

Mi método para la recogida de datos era este (NodeJS):

```
var newProyect = req.body;
    proyect.create(newProyect, (err, proyect) => {
        if(err){
            res.status(500).send({message: 'Error al añadir el nuevo registro.'});
        }else{
            res.status(200).send({proyect: proyect});
        } 
    });
```

y mi modelo este (Angular):

```
export class Proyect{
    constructor(
        public _id: string,
        public name: string,
        public subName: string,
        public description: string,
        public author: string,
        public date: string,
        public campo: string
    ){
    }
}
```

Me dí cuenta, de que la propiedad "_id" y "_v" se crean de forma automática una vez registrados en la base de datos. Y mi modelo en NodeJs era este:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var proyectSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    subName: String,
    description: String,
    author: String,
    date: String,
    campo: String
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('proyect', proyectSchema);
```

Lo que ocurría era que enviaba un objeto "proyect", creado con la propiedad "_id", aunque iba vacía, no concordaba con el modelo de NodeJs. Con lo que daba un error, se creaba un objeto con una propiedad de más, y el servidor mostraba un error interno (500). De todas formas, necesitaba la propiedad "_id" para usarla en uno de los componentes de Angular, así que necesitaba esa propiedad declarada en el modelo "Proyect", al menos, con mis concocimientos, llegué a la solución replanteando el método de recogida de datos en los controladores de NodeJs, dejándolo así:

```
function addProyect(req, res){
    var params = req.body;
    var proyect = new ProyectSchema();

    proyect.name = params.name;
    proyect.subName = params.subName;
    proyect.description = params.description;
    proyect.author = params.author;
    proyect.date = params.date;
    proyect.campo = params.campo;

    proyect.save((err, proyectStored) => {
        if(err){
            res.status(500).send({message : 'Error al guardar el nuevo regitro.'});
        }else{
            res.status(200).send({proyect : proyectStored});
        }
    });
}
```

De esta forma, recogía solo los datos que yo necesitaba para introducir un nuevo registro a la base de datos. El campo "_id" que aún así venia vacío lo desechaba, simplemente no usándolo. 
Espero que esto sirva de ayuda para alguien. En cuanto a que me diese un problema con respecto al CORS, era a causa de una ruta mal nombrada, pero está todo arreglado. Quizá sea una mala forma de desarrollar código, pero bueno, voy sacándome las castañas.
Un saludo.